# C read input file and sort ascending for one type

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, file-io

I am writing a program that takes a file input and saves it to an array. The problem is I'm not entirely sure if I should do a 2d array or not.Specifically my while loop that I've heard `!feof` is probably not the way to go. I also need to find out the average of the city_mpg and highway_mpg and then add that to the array as another column. After the column is added i need to sort it ascending. How would I find the averages if its a 1D array and then add it to another column? If it was 2D couldn't I just specify `[1][4]` and `[1][5]` and do an operation like that then save it as `[1][6]` and so on or should I stick with Malloc?

Input file:

```
Mercury Sable 2009 18 28
Jeep Wrangler 2016 17 21
Honda civic 2015 31 41
Toyota Corolla 2015 30 42
Toyta Prius 2010 51 48
Ford Escape 2013 23 33
Ford Fusion 2013 25 37
Acura MDX 2014 20 28
Lexus RX 2013 32 28
```

Program incomplete:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CARS 1000 //no more than 1000 cars
#define MAX_STR  30  //str wont be longer than 30

struct car {                       // declare my structure
    char *make;                    // pointers for char and declares my vars
    char *model;                  
    int manufacture_year;
    int city_mpg;
    int highway_mpg;
    int average_mpg;
};

//sorts array based on average mpg here

int main(void) { //main function
    int cars = 0;
    int c;
    struct car *data;
    char make[MAX_STR+1];  //char will be 30 + 1 for null char
    char model[MAX_STR+1];
    int year, city, highway; //declares ints
    FILE *file; //declares input file
    FILE *file2; //declares output file

    file = fopen("cars.txt", "r"); //opens car.txt as read
    if(file == NULL) { //if file is null
        printf("File error\n"); //throws error
        return 1;
    }

    data = malloc(MAX_CARS * sizeof(struct car)); //allocates memory for array by max cars for pointers
    if(data == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error\n"); //error if memory is a issue just incase mainly used for testing
        return 1;
    }

    while(fscanf(file, "%30s %30s %d %d %d", make, model, &year, &city, &highway) == 5) { //reads the data with a while loop
        if(cars >= MAX_CARS) { //just a check if file is more than 1k
            printf("Too many cars\n"); //outputs result if too many cars
            break;
        }
        data[cars].make = strdup(make);             // makes a copy of the strings
        data[cars].model = strdup(model);            
        data[cars].manufacture_year = year;         // copies the data so that it is headed properly
        data[cars].city_mpg = city;                 // copies the data so that it is headed properly
        data[cars].highway_mpg = highway;           // copies the data so that it is headed properly
        data[cars].average_mpg = (city + highway) / 2; //gets the average mpg
        cars++;                                     // loop counter
    }
    fclose(file); //closes file

    file2 = fopen("sorted_cars.txt", "a+"); //opens new file or creates one if there isnt one

    fprintf(file2,"Make Model           Year City mpg Highway mpg Average mpg\n"); //prints to new txt file
    for(c=0; c<cars; c++) {
        sprintf(model, "%s %s", data[c].make, data[c].model);    //sprintf sends formatted output to a string
        fprintf(file2,"%-20s %4d  %4d        %4d        %4d\n", model, data[c].manufacture_year,data[c].city_mpg, data[c].highway_mpg, data[c].average_mpg); //prints to oufile
    }

    // free the memory, It tries to allocate enough memory to hold the old string (plus a null character to mark the end of the string)
    while(--cars >= 0) {
        free(data[cars].model);     
        free(data[cars].make);       
    }
    free(data); //frees the array memory
    return 0;
    }
```

Expected outcome:

```
Make Model     year city mpg highway mpg average mpg
Jeep Wrangler  2016    17          21          19
Mercury Sable  2009    18          28          23
and so on...
```

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it usually helps that it actually *is* complete and verifiable. In other words that it compiles and runs. Unless you're asking about build or run-time errors. And besides the expected output, also include the *actual* output.

Comment: Also please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: In your own code, each type of car is represented by an object of type `struct car`.  You need to accommodate several such objects; the way you seem to have settled on to do that is via an array of `struct car` (which is fine).  Why would you need a 2D array for that?

Comment: If you want to store gas mileage as well then you could either add a field for it to `struct car`, or maintain a separate array of gas mileage in parallel with the array of car types.

Comment: There is too much to-do for a simple answer. For example, make and model members should be character arrays (or pointers).

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code, it does not compile and it is unclear what you want from us. See [ask]

Comment: You can avoid the use of `feof` like this: `while(fscanf(file, "%s %s %d %d %d", ...) == 5) {...}` and you must always check the return value of `scanf` family calls anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a few tweaks to your code, with some comments. It uses a 1-D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CARS 1000
#define MAX_STR  99

struct car {                       // array of cars appears later
    char *make;                    // pointer to string memory that will be allocated
    char *model;                   // ditto
    int manufacture_year;
    int city_mpg;
    int highway_mpg;
    int average_mpg;
};

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    // compare function for qsort
    // this is the user-supplied compare function always required by qsort
    // qsort does not know or care about the data type, only its dimensions
    // so I cast the void pointers to our local data type
    struct car *aa = (struct car*)a;
    struct car *bb = (struct car*)b;
    if(aa->average_mpg > bb->average_mpg) return 1;
    if(aa->average_mpg < bb->average_mpg) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int cars = 0;
    int c;
    struct car *data;
    char make[MAX_STR+1];
    char model[MAX_STR+1];
    int year, city, highway;
    FILE *file;

    // set up
    file = fopen("cars.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("File error\n");                     // finish messages with a newline
        return 1;
    }
    // allocate dynamic memory for the array, for maximum cars specified
    // the argument is the total memory requirement
    // could have been a global array of struct but it's bad practice
    data = malloc(MAX_CARS * sizeof(struct car));
    if(data == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // read the data, controlling the loop with fscanf return value
    // feof is commonly, but incorrectly used, and since it is essential to check the 
    // return value from fscanf, this kills two birds with one stone
    while(fscanf(file, "%49s %49s %d %d %d", make, model, &year, &city, &highway) == 5) {
        if(cars >= MAX_CARS) {
            printf("Too many cars\n");
            break;
        }
        data[cars].make = strdup(make);             // make a copy of the strings
        data[cars].model = strdup(model);
        data[cars].manufacture_year = year;         // copy the data
        data[cars].city_mpg = city;
        data[cars].highway_mpg = highway;
        data[cars].average_mpg = (city + highway) / 2;
        cars++;                                     // track the number of records
    }
    fclose(file);

    // sort the records, qsort needs to know the width of each element, 
    // and how many many, and you tell it your own comparison callback function
    qsort(data, cars, sizeof *data, cmp);

    // print the data
    printf("Make Model           Year City mpg Highway mpg Average mpg\n");
    for(c=0; c<cars; c++) {
        sprintf(model, "%s %s", data[c].make, data[c].model);   // to make alignment easy
        printf("%-20s %4d  %4d        %4d        %4d\n", model, data[c].manufacture_year,
                    data[c].city_mpg, data[c].highway_mpg, data[c].average_mpg);
    }

    // free the memory, note that strdup allocated memory secretly
    while(--cars >= 0) {
        free(data[cars].model);      // it was acquired by strdup
        free(data[cars].make);       // so was this
    }
    free(data);                      // now free the array memory we got ourselves
    return 0;
    }
```

Program output:

```
Make Model           Year City mpg Highway mpg Average mpg
Jeep Wrangler        2016    17          21          19
Mercury Sable        2009    18          28          23
Acura MDX            2014    20          28          24
Ford Escape          2013    23          33          28
Lexus RX             2013    32          28          30
Ford Fusion          2013    25          37          31
Honda civic          2015    31          41          36
Toyota Corolla       2015    30          42          36
Toyta Prius          2010    51          48          49
```

Comment: @user5468794 I have fleshed out the comments a bit. I advise you to read the man page for `qsort` for a fuller description.

Comment: One last thing that could be helpful, if it was read into the program from a file how would you write the output to a specified file?

Comment: Open a text file for writing, and use `fprintf(file, ...)` where I have used `printf`. There actually is a (not obvious) bug in the code - where I make up a string of the car type for output, `model[]` might not have enough room if the car details concatenate to more than 99 characters. Not very likely, but still a potential hole.

Comment: I have fixed the bug by restricting the make & model input length further. Please note that make and model must be single-word names too, because `%s` stops at the first whitespace. So the make "Aston Martin" won't work.

Comment: I would want to leave file open then replace `printf()` with `fprintf(file2,...)` then close both correct?

Comment: Why leave the first one open? Just use the same file pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Lets split up your questions to 2 main parts:

The first being - "Do I need feof? Is there any alternatives?"

And the second being - "Is there any practical use for 2D arrays in this case?"

So I'm gonna start with the first question.
I don't recommend to use feof, because feof tests the end-of-file indicator, rather than the stream itself. And that means that another function is actually responsible for setting the EOF when reached, which is bad.

A good alternative to this is to read and always check if there's more to read or it's the end, and to do that you need to always "read and check".

For example when using getc, check always that the result isn't -1. This takes care on other cases as well, usually msdn is the way to go when to check built return values.

For the second question, in this case there's no need for 2D arrays. Your car structure is built clean, dynamic and readable so you can make changes on the table afterwards, no need to create another column on a 2D array, because that will often cause confusion and less dynamic changing. For example, if suddenly you want another 5 columns in all kinds of different cases (MAX, MIN, AVG, etc etc) this may seem a little bit much tiring. Make data values as the values you want to paste out, not data structures to hold all the meta on your program. This will also help you on the selection_sort, because then you don't need to refer to the 2d array in order to sort your data, but the object itself.